# What does it mean when an article's headline starts with "TA:"?

Tags: acronyms

> TA: Bitcoin Consolidated above $36K, Why BTC Could Start A Fresh Increase

Source: https://www.newsbtc.com/analysis/btc/bitcoin-consolidated-above-36k/

I keep seeing this. What does it mean? Why do they insist on using cryptic acronyms which I never have any clue what they mean?

Comment: Do you have any other contextual citations?  The webpage breadcrumb navigation immediately above the title ("Home  Technical analysis  BTC") makes me guess at about 75% certainty this is this publishing company's house style for "Technical Analysis"

Comment: 'Why do they insist on using cryptic acronyms which I never have any clue what they mean?' displays a striking example of a Ross constraint violation.

Answer (score 2):

Technical Analysis (or Trend Analysis)

Source:

[https://www.cryptowisser.com/glossary/ta/#:~:text=TA%20stands%20for%20Technical%20Analysis,such%20cryptocurrency%20will%20move%20next](https://www.cryptowisser.com/glossary/ta/#:%7E:text=TA%20stands%20for%20Technical%20Analysis,such%20cryptocurrency%20will%20move%20next).